# Mysql select multiple values error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a sql query to select multiple states from the column "State"...how come I get #1054 - Unknown column 'Alaska' in 'where clause'  when it is a value not a column?

```
 SELECT * FROM Sheet1 WHERE State IN  (`Alaska`,  `Arizona`)
```

thanks

Steve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong quotes; for data, you need single quotes - the backtick is for column and table names:

```
SELECT * FROM `Sheet1` WHERE `State` IN  ('Alaska',  'Arizona')
```